# programmatic steps in chrome console in debugging mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to write javascript code that affects the breakpoints in debugging mode in Chrome console.

something like:

```
function someJavascriptCode() {
    console.log('will stop here for debugging');
    debugger; // stop!

    chrome.debugger.stepOver(); // just like clicking F10 in the console when in a breakpoint
    console.log('This line just happened because of the previous line');
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Chrome offers https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger for extensions, I don't think such an api is available for regular scripts for security reasons though.

Comment: Imagine that your program is you are flying to a star. You switched on a fridge and put yourself into it. And you expecting that after a thousand years of flight your body gets out from the fridge and push the unfridge button for unfridge. So there should be something who will do this job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing like that is implemented, nor is it likely to be in that manner because it doesn't make any sense to have functions to control the debugger in runtime code.  It could possibly be done with some kind of directive, but I doubt anything like that exists and I can't really think of any genuine use cases.

If you're looking to do this externally, you might want to take a look at the [remote debugging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol) or writing a [debugger extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger).